# Kali Linux running in VMware problems related to Wi-Fi

Tags: wifi, vmware, kali-linux

Today I installed the latest version of [VMware](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VMware) to run [Kali Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kali_Linux). All installation went fine, but when I started the virtual machine, I found that Kali Linux was already connected to the Internet through a wired connection and no Wi-Fi was found.

I want to test penetration testing in my laptop, but there was no wlan0 detected in my laptop even though I use it to connect to Wi-Fi in Windows.
Does this mean I cannot use my inbuilt Wi-Fi card for this purpose and I have to get one external USB Wi-Fi card?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is no software that allows you to use your internal wireless adaptor to connect a virtual machine to wifi.

If you need to connect to wifi on the vm you will need an external usb wifi adaptor.

And you would have to change the network setting to bridge mode and connect it to your external usb wifi adaptor.

i had the same problem a week ago. i solved it by getting a usb wifi adaptor